# Is it C++ standard-compliant to define a variable using `A<int>::template B<int> x;`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-construction, portability

The following code is accepted by gcc, vc++, and clang.

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
    template<class U>
    struct B
    {};
};

int main()
{
    A<int>::B<int> y; // OK as expected
    A<int>::template B<int> x; // Also OK! Is this standard-compliant?
};
```

Is it C++ standard-compliant to define a variable using `A<int>::template B<int> x;`?

Comment: B is a template-dependent type template, so the second syntax is perfectly correct.

Comment: Could you refer me to the page of the standard that specifies this usage? Thanks.

Comment: @peppe Not a duplicate, because you do not need to use `template` here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour oh. So it would only be the case with, say, `A<W>::template B<int>` within a scope with a template parameter `W` ?

Comment: @Quentin: Indeed; it's needed in a dependent context, when the interpretation of the name depends on unknown template parameters. Here, it's not needed, since the template has been specialised and we know exactly what `B` is in that specialiation. (Sorry, I had brief second thoughts and removed my comment saying that it's not dependent here).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thank you very much ! I'll sleep wiser tonight :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though it is a non-normative note, I think an answer can be given by n3797[temp.names]/6

> As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary; i.e., when the *nested-name-specifier* or the expression on the left of the `->` or `.` is not dependent on a template-parameter, or the use does not appear in the scope of a template.

In the OP's example, the prefix `template` is used outside the scope of a template, and the preceding *nested-name-specifier* is not dependent. Therefore, the prefix `template` is not required, but allowed here.

---

[expr.prim.general]/8

> *qualified-id*:
>        *nested-name-specifier* `template`<sub>*opt*</sub>   *unqualified-id*

Plus [temp.names]/5

> A name prefixed by the keyword `template` shall be a *template-id* or the name shall refer to a class template.

[temp.names]/1 says that `B<int>` is indeed a (*simple-*)*template-id*.

Comment: It all is valid for C++11+, not for C++98/03. Am I right?

Comment: @Constructor In C++03, you could use the keyword `template` even if the *nested-type-name* is not dependent; but you were not allowed to use it outside the scope of templates.